# If the $ in a question title is escaped, the \ is shown in the window title

Tags: bug, title, latex, window-title

The title of questions that contain a $ that needs to be escaped (the $ is part of code not the start of LaTeX) are not displaying properly in the browser *window* title. The `\` used for escaping is shown. For example:

[Got “Error in ans$res: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors” when rolling forecast using rugarch](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/34325/848)

To recap, the bug is: the title on the page doesn't *not* show the \ whereas the window title does.

It looks like this:

[image: Extra \ before $]

Comment: Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO9EX.png) of the bug. Feel free to include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks, added @Laurel